# How do fishmen produce water when there is no water around?

Tags: one-piece

I was watching the fight between Luffy and Hody, when Hody tries to use the attack where he shoots water bullets (I think it's called Yabusame).

So I was wondering how he can produce so much water when there is no water around him? Is that some quality of the fishmen or am I missing something?

Here's the image from the fight.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As state on [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hody_Jones#Abilities_and_Powers), Hody's body under the influence of Energy Steroids can produce water, so he can make a drip of water even when he wasn't soaked

> After overdosing on Energy Steroids, Hody appeared to drip with water even though he wasn't soaked, suggesting that he'd been secreting it.

So I think it's just like sweat, but with greater amount of water

Answer (score 5):

Well if you think of it in a real life standpoint, the air is full of water particles, gather tons of it together and I suppose you can do something like that xD. That's my suggestion, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Fishman Karate Allow you to control water within a certain vicinity, so controlling water particles in the air is possible, and even controlling and using the water within one's body, and one's body almost purely consist of water.

Jinbe also explains Fishman Karate in Chapter 629.